# Gnome 3 doesn't run on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, gdm3

Several weeks ago I installed Kali Linux on my laptop (Asus X53BR). I installed it successfully but the when system started, I only had a command line and no login manager (gdm3) running.

I have tried everything to fix it; I updated and upgraded system and `gdm3` several times. Nothing worked and I gave up. Yesterday, I tried installation one more time. Same problem but this time I tried every method to fix this on first five pages on Google but nothing worked. And suddenly `Gnome` started and graphical desktop appeared. I have no idea how. But after restart the same problem: only command window. Please help me solve this problem.

Details:
When gdm accidentally started, I was trying to connect to the internet using the command prompt. After this accident, I reviewed my command history and there were gnome3 typed in the command window. I don't remember if I typed it or what. But any other time when I was trying run gdm3, I got this error:

```
 failed acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager
```

and something like this on second line. As I searched there could be permission issue at `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/gdm.conf` as I remember. But I was logged in as root and also changed permission to allow any user access to it but nothing changed. I also examined that conf file and there were html-like scripts mentioning gdm3 running permissions. But I don't know exactly what those scripts mean.

Comment: You will have to show what you did. And what happened.

Comment: I installed many times so I did many things. When gdm accidentaly started I was trying to connect to internet using command promt. After this accident I reviewed command history and there were gnome3 typed in command window. I don't remmember I typed it or what. But any other time when I was trying run gdm3 promt returning error like this: failed acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager and something like this on second line

Comment: You can edit your question, please do so (instead of using comments). Also add more detail if you can.

Comment: Oh it happened again. Graphical desktop suddenly started and after reboot same problem.

Comment: That does not make it any clearer. Imagine that we can not see what you are seeing.

Comment: I was installing Kali from same disc every time. If disk file were damaged and gdm libraries corrupted, should not system upgrade have fixed problem?

Comment: Yey I solved the problem. Maybe the problem were nouveau driver. I installed AMD driver and after reboot graphical desktop started.